# PHP/Laravel - Saving an image(PNG) from a base64 to an FTP Server without saving it locally

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I'm using laravel to get a post request base64. then on the controller, I want to decode the base64 to a png file and then immediately store the file to the FTP storage without saving it to my local(Public Folder) folder.
This is my **Controller**

```
 $path     = "test/image.png";
 $image    = explode(',',$imgbg);
 $base64   = $image[1];
 $result   = base64_decode($base64);

 file_put_contents("ori.png", $result);

 Storage::disk('ftp-dev')->put($path, file_get_contents("ori.png"));
```

as of now, it save the file locally and then get the file contents to save it to an FTP server. Is there a way to do it so it doesn't save the file locally and just save it in the FTP server? any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: by locally, do you mean the temp files that are created? if you dont mind me asking, why exactly do you want to stop temp files from being created? they shouldnt take up space for long anyway.

Comment: by locally I mean it saves to the public folder.its not a matter of space or for a second, it cant be store locally

Answer (score 2):

My solution is:

```
Storage::disk('ftp-dev')->put($path, $result);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I tried it. It says there was no stream file or directory

Comment: have you tried to dump the `$result` and see what's inside ? i suspect that `$result` is empty / null

Edit: ahh i see you explode the full encoded image, try this instead
`Storage::disk('ftp-dev')->put($path, $imgbg);`